# Multiple matrix operations in C

Tags: c, matrix, statistics

I need to write function that calculates beta coefficients for multiple linear regression in C. I'm trying to calculate these coefficients from matrix equation, which requires multiple operations on large matrices. I've already wrote library with all necessary functions and they all work properly when used for single operations. However, when I'm trying to combine them to calculate coefficients I'm getting wrong results. Here are my functions for matrices operations:

```
void display(int row, int col, double mat[row][col])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
            printf("  %f", mat[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void transpose(int n, int m, double matrix[n][m], double result[m][n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            result[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}


void switchRows(int n, double mat[n][n], int r1, int r2)
{
    double temp[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = mat[r1][i];
        mat[r1][i] = mat[r2][i];
        mat[r2][i] = temp[i];
    }
}

int luDecompose(int n, double mat[n][n], int P[n])
{
    int i, j, k, imax;
    double maxA, absA;


    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        P[i] = i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        maxA = 0.0;
        imax = i;

        for (k = i; k < n; k++) {
            absA = fabs(mat[k][i]);
            if (absA > maxA) {
                maxA = absA;
                imax = k;
            }
        }

        if (maxA < 0) return 0;

        if (imax != i) {

            j = P[i];
            P[i] = P[imax];
            P[imax] = j;
            switchRows(n, mat, i, imax);
            P[n]++;
        }

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            mat[j][i] /= mat[i][i];

            for (k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
                mat[j][k] -= mat[j][i] * mat[i][k];
        }
    }

    return 1;
}



void invert(int n, double mat[n][n], int P[n], double res[n][n])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (P[i] == j)
                res[i][j] = 1.0;
            else
                res[i][j] = 0.0;

            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
                res[i][j] -= mat[i][k] * res[k][j];
        }

        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int k = i + 1; k < n; k++)
                res[i][j] -= mat[i][k] * res[k][j];

            res[i][j] = res[i][j] / mat[i][i];
        }
    }
}


void multiplyMatrices(int n1, int m1, int n2, int m2, double mat1[n1][m1], double mat2[n2][m2], double result[n1][m2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < m2; k++)
            {
                result[i][k] += mat1[i][j] * mat2[j][k];
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is my main function with some data for testing:

```
    double y[10][1] = {{44},{24},{38},{48},{73},{62},{66},{29},{60},{68}};
    double x[10][2] = {{1, 71},{1, 98},{1, 111},{1, 111},{1, 114},{1, 116},{1, 120},{1, 127},{1, 130},{1, 136}};


    double betas[2][1];

    int m = 2;
    int n = 10;

    double transp_x[m][n];

    transpose(n, m, x, transp_x);

    double x_mult[m][m];

    multiplyMatrices(m, n, n, m, transp_x, x, x_mult);

    double x_inv[m][m];
    double P[m];

    luDecompose(m, x_mult, P);
    invert(m, x_mult, P, x_inv);

    double x_inv_transp[m][n];

    multiplyMatrices(m, m, m, n, x_inv, transp_x, x_inv_transp);

    multiplyMatrices(m, n, n, 1, x_inv_transp, y, betas);
```

With given data:
betas[0][0] = 94432444972981371756748187760253915639585355574358671491425000489037615984453556356121867212102849003520.000000, which obviously is incorrect and betas[1][0] = 0.367032, which is correct result. However, when I decrease number of x and y rows to 9 and less I'm getting right results. I don't have much experience with C programming, therefore I'd be really grateful for any help. I'm aware that this is not the best way to calculate linear regression, however I was asked to do it this way.

Comment: Where did you set result[i][k] to 0 before adding to it in the multiplication???

Comment: also note that there are lots of libraries (e.g. try searching for BLAS and LAPACK) that do this sort of thing. a lot of effort has been put into making them computationally efficient and numerically stable